# jenkins shell build step with variable containing a single quote

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to use jenkins to schedule a repeated job to rsync from a remote directory.  Unfortunately I only have ssh password access (no key) so I'm using sshpass to authenticate.  The password contains a single quote, and no matter what I do, jenkins always puts a backslash in front of the single quote.

Details:

- jenkins is running on centos, installed via yum
- build step is a shell
- command in shell is basically `sshpass -p my'pass rsync -avc me@remotehost.com: /my/dest/dir/

variations I've tried:

- put the password in a file then use sshpass -f

  - reports authentication fails
- put the above command in a script file, have the jenkins build run that script
- use jenkins credentials / associated variables
- all variations of double quoting / string concatenation

Note that all of the things I've tried work fine on the command line and/or via crontab (I'm trying to use jenkins instead of crontab though...)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Groovy multiline string literal for the shell block:

```
stage{
  sh """
    sshpass -p my'pass rsync -avc me@remotehost.com: /my/dest/dir/
  """
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This led me to get groovy installed, however "sh" doesn't work, and neither does including groovy commands in the stage { ... }.  When I try googling "sh" I don't get very far, any suggestions for how to get this working in my jenkins?

Comment: can u provide your Jenkinsfile ?

Comment: Thank you, I can't fine the Jenkinsfile anywhere.  I did find in the JENKINS_HOME, no luck.  What should I do get that setup correctly?